# node util promisify working example please

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand promises. Can someone point out what is wrong with this code? What needs to be added or edited to return the value passed?

```
const util = require('util')

const echo = (word) => {
    return word
}

let echoPromise = util.promisify(echo)

let promise = echoPromise()
promise("promise").then((data) => {  // tried promise.then(...)
    console.log(data)   // echo's 'promise' ?
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error
}) 
console.log(echo('word'))  // echos word
```

Comment: update: let promise = echoPromise

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand your response.